# Bash Uniq options

Tags: bash, shell

I have 20 files. In each file I have a list of the occurring words and their frequency.

Example:

```
 2 représentant 
 3 reproduire 
 2 réseau 
 1 rester 
 3 reste 
 1 résumer
```

I used this command to merge between these 20 files

```
cat *.txt > tous.txt | sort | uniq -ci  | sort -k3
```

The result was for example:

```
2  2 représentant 
1  6 représentant 
5  3 reproduire
2  3 reproduire  
6  3 réseau
1  1 réseau
etc..
```

But what I want is to make it calculate the number of occurrence of each word without writing it many times. What I want is:

```
8 representant
6 reproduire
4 réseau
...
```

I can do it with awk:

```
awk '{tab[$2]+=$1} END {for(i in tab){printf("%7d %s\n", tab[i], i) | "sort -k2"}}' ~/Bureau/Projet/data/dico/*.dico.forme.txt > ~/Bureau/Projet/data/input/black.txt
```

Any other suggestions by using for ex if?

Comment: You cannot accomplish this using a simple sort and uniq pipeline.  There is no good way to use only those tools to grab the preexisting counts and sum them.  You could do it with a more complex Bash script, but Awk is the simpler and likely best way to approach it.

Comment: Based on your description, shouldn't the count of total number word occurances be:
`10 représentant`, 
`21 reproduire`,
`19 réseau`
That is, the total of the word occurrences listed in each line times the number of times that those counts occur, _plus_ any other such counts for the same word?

Comment: é will not count as e

Comment: Please show us the exact command you used. The command in your question: `cat *.txt > tous.txt | sort | uniq -ci  | sort -k3` will not do what you say it does. The output of `cat *.txt` is written to `tous.txt`, and will not be available as the input to `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is don't do the counting in the first place. There seems to be no easy way to do it with `uniq` but you can count it using Awk or loops.

1. Combine all the data (assume space-separated)

   ```
   cat *.txt >all.txt
   ```

   > ```
   > cat all.txt  
   > 2 hi  
   > 2 test  
   > 3 try  
   > 3 hi  
   > 5 test  
   > 3 try
   > ```
2. Count again

   With Awk:

   ```
   sort -k2,2 all.txt | awk '{a[$2] += $1} END{for (i in a) print a[i],i}'
   ```

   Output:

   ```
     5 hi  
     7 test  
     6 try
   ```

... Or you can do it with a `while` loop (less efficient):

```
while read -r a; do
    echo "$(grep -w "$a" all.txt|cut -d ' ' -f1|paste -sd+|bc)" "$a"
done< <(cut -d ' ' -f2 all.txt|sort -u)
```

or reverse what `uniq -c` did:

```
while read -r a b; do
    yes "$b" |head -n "$a"
done <all.txt | sort| uniq -c
```

Comment: I agree with "don't do the counting in the first place" but the rest is just horrible.

Comment: I'm afraid not. You [read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [don't quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and you still unnecessarily use a temporary file and fail to clean it up afterwards; but more generally, the OP's Awk script is already doing a much better job of solving the problem efficiently.

Comment: Your Awk refactoring is a bit of an improvement but it loses the sort order. In any event, I'd be hesitant to remove my downvote as long as your shell script doesn't even pass http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: @tripleee all "No issues detected!" using #!/bin/bash now, sorry i dont know shellcheck

Comment: Reading the entire file on every iteration just to `grep` it is very inefficient. The use of `echo` with backticks also sets off some odd olfactory sensations, though it's not technically a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: I reluctantly removed my downvote for all the effort you put in, but really, the TLDR of this answer is, "I have no *better* solution than the OP's Awk script".

Comment: The `grep` will be wrong if one word is a substring of another. The simplest workaround is to not try to fix that code because of the other issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store intermediate results in `tous.txt` and no need really to keep the entire array in memory, though this is a minor efficiency hack which won't make much difference unless your data set is large.

```
sort -k2,2 *.txt |
awk 'NR>1 && $2 != prev { print sum, prev; sum = 0 }
    { prev = $2; sum += $1 }
    END { print sum, prev }'
```

Notice how the `END` block repeats (part of) the main flow. (Missing the last output line is a common bug with this general approach.)

As already suggested by others, if you can avoid the `*.txt` files and go straight to a `sort | uniq -c` with the entire raw input, that might end up being more elegant and efficient.

Comment: Notice that `*.txt` will match `tous.txt` so remove that before running this.